# Get an id value from list item with multiple ids in android

Tags: android, list

I am trying to retrieve a certain id when an item in list is clicked on.

How can i retrieve the value +id/name? I want to use it in an alert dialog ash shown below.

I'm currently working with a simple toast which just shows "name" at the moment when a list item is clicked on

Here is the xml code for my list item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image" android:textSize="20dip"   
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:src="@drawable/stub" android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
  android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Alert dialog code:

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
                    String artistname = "get +id/name here";
                    String items[] = {"Youtube", "Soundcloud"};
                         @Override
                         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                 int position, long id) {

                             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                                     AlertDialog.Builder(JsonActivity.this);

                             builder.setTitle(artistname);
                             builder.setItems(items, new   
                                     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                             }
                             });

                             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                             alert.show();
                         }});




                }
```

Comment: What is your question....?

Comment: i don't understand your question, please elaborate

Comment: @Pragnani How can i retrieve the value +id/name? I want to use it in an alert dialog ash shown above.

Comment: @Shoshi i have rephrased the question

Comment: try my answer.. let me know if you got what i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                 int position, long id) {
//name of the artist...
String name=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText();

}
```

I think this is what you want...I hope this will help you

Comment: i just get this "Multiple markers at this line
 - view cannot be resolved
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to 
  String"

Comment: ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

When we display a list using Adapter. 
In the getView method we fetch a value from a collection on the basis of position of item in the list. The data source of the adapter i am talking about.
like this.

```
public View getView(){
   holder.name.setText(data.get(position));
}
```

When a list item get clicked you will get the position that get clicked using listItemOnClickListener. In that callback
call the get method of the data source again to get the element you paste over the list item.
Hope you got the point. As i didn't posted much code to support it.